# Wrapping a function within an if statement in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a function that removes part of a string after a comma, eg:

`=LEFT(B3,FIND(",",B3)-1)`

Eg: `123 West St, Sydney` becomes `123 West St`.

This works fine, but some of my cells don't have commas and so I get the `#VALUE!` error on these.

I've Googled and found 'IF(ISNUMBER)` and have made:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",",B3)),LEFT(B3,FIND(",",B3)-1))`

but this just returns 'FALSE' on cells with no comma.

Is there a way to wrap this in an 'if' statement? Something like

`if (B3 contains ','){=LEFT(B3,FIND(",",B3)-1)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have omitted the 2nd parameter to IF function. That is what will return when the condition is false. Since you omitted, it FALSE is the default return. Try :

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",",B3)),LEFT(B3,FIND(",",B3)-1), B3)`

Although this could be shortened to :
`IFERROR(LEFT(B3,SEARCH(",",B3)-1), B3)`